# ? appending to end of pathname after redirect 301 in htaccess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This should be simple but I've not been able to work out the problem. I'm sure it's a seconds answer for somebody.

I have a rewrite in my htaccess file as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /product\.php\?categoryfilename=([A-Za-z0-9-%.]+)&category=([A-Za-z0-9-%.]+)&id=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%3-P.html? [R=301,L]
```

The rewrite works
If I enter:

```
www.mysite.co.uk/product.php?categoryfilename=all-products.php&category=All%20products&id=MY-PRODUCT
```

it redirects to:

```
http://www.mysite.co.uk/MY-PRODUCT-P.html
```

THEN I have what should be a simple redirect:

Redirect 301 /MY-PRODUCT-P.html http://www.mysite.co.uk/MY-PRODUCT-123-P.html?

This should be a static redirect but it is appending a pesky ? to the end of the result.

If I remove the ? from the end of the redirect then I get php variables appended left over from the original messy pathname in the first rewriterule

Many thanks

Comment: Please use the correct terminology. You are rewriting FROM /name-P.html TO /product.php?var=val&var=val&var=val, etc. The "outside world" static URI customers see is /name-P.html, and the dynamic URI that your PHP code sees is /product.php?...

Answer (score 0):

You can't match or manipulate `QUERY_STRING` using `Redirect` directive. Use mod_rewrite instead. Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/product\.php\?categoryfilename=([^&]*)&category=([^&]*)&id=([^&\s]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%3-P.html? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(MY-PRODUCT)-(P\.html)$ /$1-123-$2? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi, I'm really sorry. In my question I've written about totally the wrong line of code. I was working on this late last night and got up early this morning to carry on. Tired eyes I'm afraid. The correct lines of code are now in the question!

Comment: The first rewriterule is dynamic. There are a range of different possibilities that will all redirect and then %3 will be used to create the new pathname. At that point some products will need redirecting again because their name has slightly changed. This is why I have added a second step with the redirect 301. So I can't just amend the first rewriterule as this will mess up all the products that are perfectly OK after the rewrite. My code works perfectly apart from the fact that it adds this ? onto the end of the pathname after the redirect301...